# Cannot log-in to ReadyKit after changing a migration

Tags: php, laravel-5, compiler-errors, vuejs3

After migrating a new column to a data table, midway through my project I became unable to access the users data table use the login functionality of my app that had been working perfectly before. This is the error message that I receive.

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> null (reading 'company_banner')"

When I first had this issue I went through a long troubleshooting process and eventually elected to just switch to a different database and reimplement my project until I could isolate what caused everything to go wrong. What I believe happened is that I added a new column to a datatable part way through the project, for some reason this caused some greater issue that I am still unable to solve, despite finding the source of the incident.

Comment: You're going to have to do some troubleshooting, and show some code. As of right now, this is very vague. What is `company_banner` supposed to be attached to, is it getting the data for that, are you getting a valid response from the API, and if not, what is the error and the code generating the error?